# How programmatically assign selected menu to superfish menu...?

Tags: theming, routes, navigation

In my custom theme there is an option to choose navigation menu and type of navigation menu (TB Megamenu and Superfish Menu) from a select list in theme settings page. In my tpl file am able to pass selected menu into TB Megamenu using the following piece of code.

```
if (module_exists('tb_megamenu')) {
$block = block_load('tb_megamenu','SELECTED Menu');
$output =   _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
print render($output);
}
```

From my research i didn't any methods to assign a selected menu to superfish. By using following code my **main-menu** is changed to **superfish**.

```
$block = block_load('superfish', 1);
```

How can i assign a selected nagivation menu as superfish menu..??
I am using [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) Module version = "7.x-1.9"
Welcome for all suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can done it by using following code..

```
variable_set('superfish_menu_1', 'MENU MACHINE NAME');
```

Using this we are updating the default menu value in superfish block 1